# Promise: Ignore Catch and Return to Chain

Tags: javascript, promise, chain

Is it possible to ignore a catch and return back to the chain?

```
promiseA()        // <-- fails with 'missing' reason
  .then(promiseB) // <-- these are not going to run 
  .then(promiseC)
  .catch(function(error, ignore){
     if(error.type == 'missing'){
        ignore()  // <-- ignore the catch and run promiseB and promiseC
     }
  })
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: `.then` has 2 arguments.. `fulfill` and `reject`.. You can deal with `reject`

Comment: @RayonDabre Thanks for your answer but I'm not really sure what do you mean. Please can you show an example?

Comment: It takes two functions as arguments: then(onFulFill, onReject)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's the synchronous analogy:

```
try {
  actionA(); // throws
  actionB(); // skipped
  actionC(); // skipped
} catch (e) {
  // can't resume
}
```

but you want:

```
try{
   try {
      actionA(); // throws
   } catch (e) {
      if(error.type !== 'missing'){
         throw error; // abort chain
      }
      // keep going
  }
  actionB(); // executes normally if error type was 'missing'
  actionC();
} catch (e) {
  // handle errors which are not of type 'missing'.
}
```

Here's the promise version:

```
asyncActionA()        // <-- fails with 'missing' reason
   .catch(error => {
      if(error.type !== 'missing'){
         throw error; // abort chain. throw is implicit Promise.reject(error); 
      }
      // keep going, implicit: return Promise.resolve();
   })
   .asyncActionB(promiseB) // <-- runs
   .asyncActionC(promiseC)
   .catch(err => {
      // handle errors which are not of type 'missing'.
   });
```

Comment: MG, I updated to so that the synchronous and asynchronous versions are in fact the same, logically, since you wrote "Here's the promise version". Np if you revert because you think being concise is more important than being exact.

Answer (score 2):

If you need just ignore all error in promiseA, you can just do it like that:

```
promiseA()  
  .catch(function(error){
      //just do nothing, returns promise resolved with undefined
  })  
  .then(promiseB)
  .then(promiseC)
```

If you need to run promiseB only when `error.type == 'missing'`, you can do that:

```
promiseA()       
  .catch(function(error, ignore){
     if(error.type == 'missing'){
        return promiseB.then(promiseC)  
     }
  })
```

Comment: The main point it that `catch` function also returns promise, so you can use it to implement fallback logic and chain result of it

Comment: No nested `.then()` calls please.

Comment: @Madara'sGhost why not?

Comment: Nested `.then()` are ok in certain cases, e.g. if you need to make detour through side chain on some condition. Of course, one chain is more readable and cleaner, but "No nested `then`" is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and safest way to ignore promise errors is void that error. This approach is ESLint friendly too.

```
const myPromise1 =async()=>{
  throw new Error('explicitly rejected')
}
const myPromise2 =async()=>{
  console.log('passed');
}

myPromise1()
  .then(myPromise2())
  .catch(e=>void e)
```