# Continuing Promise Chain on browser.wait() Timeout

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

I have the following code:

```
.then(function() {
    return buttonClick();
})
// BEGIN
.then(function() {
    return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(anotherButton), timeOut)
        .then(function() {
            anotherButton.click();
        })
})
.then(function() {
    return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(yetAnotherButton), timeOut)
        .then(function() {
            yetAnotherButton.click();
        })
})
// END
.then(function() {
    browser.wait(do some things);
})
```

I need to make the code in between `BEGIN` and `END` execute only when `return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(anotherButton), timeOut)` succeeds. If the above does not succeed, I would just like to resume the chain at the `browser.wait(do some things);`

I've been trying several different ways of achieving this and have found some luck in doing something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596925/promise-ignore-catch-and-return-to-chain) but have yet to actually get the results I'm looking for.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** According to [Protractor FAQ](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-catch-errors-such-as-elementnotfound) you can run a second function in an error case.

```
.then(function() {
    return buttonClick();
})
//wrap your BEGIN-END-part into a new function like this:
// then(function(){BEGIN-END}, function(err){failcase-execution})
.then(function(){
    // BEGIN
    .then(function() {
        return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(anotherButton), timeOut)
            .then(function() {
                anotherButton.click();
            })
    })
    .then(function() {
        return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(yetAnotherButton), timeout)
            .then(function() {
                yetAnotherButton.click();
            })
    })
}, function(err){
    //Here is your execution in error-case.
    browser.wait(do some things);
})
.then(function() {
    browser.wait(do some things);
})
```

But to me it sounds, like you're trying to test two different scopes.
Is there a reason, these two tests have to be executed within the same test case (it-block)?

Something like:

```
describe ("test", function(){
    it("executes the first part incl. Begin-End", function(){
        //eventually some steps to come here first.
        .then(function() {
            return buttonClick();
        })
        // BEGIN
        .then(function() {
            return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(anotherButton), timeOut)
                .then(function() {
                    anotherButton.click();
                })
        })
        .then(function() {
            return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(yetAnotherButton), timeOut)
                .then(function() {
                    yetAnotherButton.click();
                })
        })
    });
    it("executes the second part, which resumes anyway", function(){
        //if necessary, repeat some of the steps from before test
        .then(function() {
            return buttonClick();
        })
        .then(function() {
            browser.wait(do some things);
        })
    });
});
```

Or if you try to just figure out, if you could click the button, you could execute the clicks between BEGIN/END in a separate function, which just returns true or false (similar to what you linked to):

```
//existing part
.then(function() {
    return buttonClick();
})
.then(
    bool clicksWorked = this.optionalExecution();
)
.then(function() {
    browser.wait(do some things);
    if(!clicksWorked){console.log("Some Buttons couldn't be clicked")} 
})

//as separate function, which just returns either true or false
this.optionalExecution = function() {
    try {
        // BEGIN
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(anotherButton), timeOut)
            .then(function() {
                anotherButton.click();
            })
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(yetAnotherButton), timeOut)
            .then(function() {
                yetAnotherButton.click();
            })
        return true
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
       return false
    }
}
```

As a side remark:
Can you add a bit more context to your `.then()`-list as it's not clear to me, if your `.then()`'s all refer to an entering condition or how they're embedded in the test case.
In your current example it seems not necessary to put your actions within `.then()`-blocks. Protractor would execute line by line synchronously, also without the `.then()`'s. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451221/protractor-timing-issues)

Comment: Just re-read the Protractor FAQ and figured a nicer way. Added it via Edit to my answer:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-catch-errors-such-as-elementnotfound